# Accessing a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, api, loops, dictionary

```
{'message': 'success', 
  'people': [
        {'name': 'Sergey Ryzhikov', 'craft': 'ISS'},
        {'name': 'Kate Rubins', 'craft': 'ISS'},
        {'name': 'Sergey Kud-Sverchkov', 'craft': 'ISS'}

   ], 
   'number': 3}
```

I want to access name inside the people list in this dictionary.
Please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: I think is better if you read the documentation or some post that will teach you, in detail, how to do this.

Comment: Try `d["people"][k]["name"]` for a specific name, or `[p["name"] for p in d["people"]]` for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the people list and pick the dict attribute you want to get

```
data = {'message': 'success',
        'people': [{'name': 'Sergey Ryzhikov', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Kate Rubins', 'craft': 'ISS'},
                   {'name': 'Sergey Kud-Sverchkov', 'craft': 'ISS'}], 'number': 3}

for p in data['people']:
    print(p['name'])
```

output

```
Sergey Ryzhikov
Kate Rubins
Sergey Kud-Sverchkov
```

Comment: Any reason for down voting?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to assing a name to this dictionary, something like this

```py
dict1 = {'message': 'success', 
  'people': [
        {'name': 'Sergey Ryzhikov', 'craft': 'ISS'},
        {'name': 'Kate Rubins', 'craft': 'ISS'},
        {'name': 'Sergey Kud-Sverchkov', 'craft': 'ISS'}

   ], 
   'number': 3}
# And then this will access it, by looping over the list and printing out all of the 3 names
for i in dict['people']:
    print(i['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty straightforward piece of code.

```
d = {'message': 'success', 'people': [{'name': 'Sergey Ryzhikov', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Kate Rubins', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Sergey Kud-Sverchkov', 'craft': 'ISS'}], 'number': 3}


for data in d.get("people"):
    print(data.get("name"))
```

I will suggest you to use `.get()` method instead of square brackets to access values in dictionary to avoid exceptions.